# What happens to dissolved ions when an aqueous solution evaporates?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution

I'm working on a chemical design project where zeolite crystals containing $\ce{Na+}$ cations is ion-exchanged via an aqueous solution of $\ce{AgNO3}$, $\ce{Cu(NO3)2}$, and $\ce{Zn(NO3)2}$, also containing $\ce{HNO3}$. The solid product now containing $\ce{Ag+}$, $\ce{Cu^2+}$, and $\ce{Zn^2+}$ cations is removed from the solution and dried. I expect the remaining $\ce{Ag+}$, $\ce{Cu^2+}$, $\ce{Zn^2+}$, and $\ce{Na+}$ will precipitate with available $\ce{NO^-3}$ as the water evaporates, but what will happen with any remaining $\ce{NO^-3}$ anions? Can they react with water or air to form any solid/gaseous products?

Comment: Have you studied the ion-exchange process on a simple polymer? The polymer is sulfonated (so negatively charged). The negative group is fixed, but the hydrogen ion or any other cation is replaceable. There is always a charge neutrality. Look at this figure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_exchange#/media/File:CationExchCartoon.png

Comment: Once you have understood the cation ion-exchange process, look at the structure of your zeolite and see where Na-ion is attached.